# PyDev python3 import error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, pydev, python-3.4

I've got a PyDev project and it is configured to use Python 3 grammar with the Python3 interpreter. P3 interpreter is auto configured by Eclipse and it mainly works fine but fails to resolve some of the internal libraries. For example, I'm having issues with the multiprocessing module, PyDev throws 'Undefined variable from import:' for various things like cpu_count, Queue, Process etc.

The code runs fine but seems like PyDev is confused. Yes, there are ways around this like using '# @UndefinedVariable' or setting the interpreter to Python2 (yes, P2 doesn't complain) but I wonder if there is a proper solution?

Regards,

Comment: crickets... have always been bothered by this same bug.